# Does Eigen have solution for repair non-positive defined covariance matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, covariance-matrix

Does Eigen contains an algorithm for solving nearest correlation matrix problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SelfAdjointEigenSolver`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html) to decompose your non-positive definite matrix, edit the negative eigenvalues to something slightly positive and (manually) re-compose the matrix.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion! I really appropriate it!